# Programatically add buttons with different properties for different orientations

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-button

I need to add a button to my app at runtime, but I want to set the layout differently depending on the orientation.  For portrait I want the width to be `wrap_content`, but in landscape I need to set a fixed width.  I know how to do each of these individually, but I can't find any way to have both working in the same way that I would handle it in a XML layout file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the mobile phones orientation

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

And add the Buttons dynamically in reference

[Dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Display instance firstly:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
```

Then orientation may be called like this:

```
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

Then you can create a different layout ,

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = display.getOrientation(); 
    switch(orientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            // ToDo layout for portrait
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            // ToDo layout for landscape
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to set orientation at runtime then use,

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT | ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Create a layout like

```
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-1));
        // ARGB: Opaque Red
        ll.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
        tv.setText("sample text goes here");
        // ARGB: Opaque Green
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0x5500ff00);
        ll.addView(tv);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
        et.setText("edit me please");
        // ARGB: Solid Blue
        et.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
        ll.addView(et);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Go!");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        ll.addView(btn);
        setContentView(ll);
```